# Checking the same predicate in multiple tables in priority order

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to have a query that can accept a date parameter, and employeeid.  That's the easy part, right?!  Well the difficult part that I have is, I then need to check and see if that date and employee id exist in table1, if it does continue, if not check table2.  if it exists in table2 then move on, if it does not then check table3.  This combo will be in one of the 3 tables, but I am not sure what is the best way syntactically to set this up?

**EDIT**
Once the date is found to exist in one of the tables all processing should end.  It should not continue to the next If Exists statement.  So if the date is found in the first If Exists statement all processing should end.

```
Declare @date datetime, @employeeid varchar(10)
Set @date = '01/01/2012'
Set @employeeid = 'vnm432'
IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
      FROM firsttable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
Begin
    'Continue processing here
End
IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
          FROM secondtable
          WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
          AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
Begin
    'Continue processing here
End
IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
          FROM thirdtable
          WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
          AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
Begin
    'Continue processing here
End
```

Comment: Just `select` row values, if needed, into variables and process and `return` if `@@RowCount` is 1. Or is this not in a stored procedure?

Comment: @HABO - yes it is a stored procedure.  How would I just select row values?

Comment: I added an answer containing sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is reasonably DRY and can short circuit execution.

```
DECLARE @Flag INT;

WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Priority, employeeid, date
         FROM   T1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS Priority, employeeid, date
         FROM   T2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS Priority, employeeid, date
         FROM   T3),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   CTE1
         WHERE  employeeid = @employeeid
                AND date >= @date
                AND date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date))
SELECT @Flag =
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE Priority = 1) THEN 1
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE Priority = 2) THEN 2
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE Priority = 3) THEN 3
        END
```

[image]

It also uses a [more efficient predicate on date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) (if `employeeid, date` is indexed) than the query in the question.

Comment: what do you mean "can short circuit execution"?  Meaning take my server down?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight - can avoid accessing the other tables when the result is found.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I think that with a subquery and unions you can get this accomplished:

```
declare @foundIn varchar(15)
select @foundIn = foundIn  from 
(
select  top 1 foundIn from
(
 Select 'firsttable' as foundIn 
      FROM firsttable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date
UNION
 Select 'secondtable' as foundIn 
      FROM secondtable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date
UNION
 Select 'thirdtable' as foundIn 
      FROM thirdtable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date
) as q
) as q1

If @foundIn = 'firsttable'
    Begin
       'Continue processing here'       
    End
Else If @foundIn = 'secondtable'
    Begin
        'Continue processing here'
    End
Else If @foundIn = 'thirdtable'    
    Begin
        'Continue processing here'
    END
```

UPDATE:

Based on the new requirement to stop processing upon first match:

```
IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
      FROM firsttable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
Begin
    --Continue processing here
End
ELSE IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
      FROM secondtable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
BEGIN
    --Continue processing here
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(Select Top 1 *
      FROM thirdtable
      WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
      AND CAST(date As Date) = @date)
BEGIN
    --Continue processing here
END
```

Comment: There is no guarantee what will be assigned to `@foundIn` if more than one match and this could access tables unnecessarily.

Comment: @MartinSmith the top 1 garantees it will take only the first

Comment: No it doesn't, not without an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Now I see, I posted before read the updated requierement, "Once the date is found to exist in one of the tables all processing should end"

Comment: @E-Bat so will this stop processing once the relevant date is found or will it iterate all tables?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight as it is right now it will process al tables I thing, but you could use the if - else if construction to solve your issue. I will Update the answer to match this requirement.

Comment: @E-Bat this produces an error of Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a response to a comment from the OP. Note that it does not use a [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) date comparison in the `where` clause, one of the benefits of Dr Smith's answer.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Employees as Table ( EmployeeId VarChar(10), HireDate DateTime, ShoeSize VarChar(6) );
insert into @Employees ( EmployeeId, HireDate, ShoeSize ) values
  ( 'vnm123', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '9' ), ( 'vnm432', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '12W' ), ( 'xyzzy', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '6N' );
select * from @Employees;
declare @Victims as Table ( EmployeeId VarChar(10), HireDate DateTime, ShoeSize VarChar(6) );
insert into @Victims ( EmployeeId, HireDate, ShoeSize ) values
  ( 'vnm123', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '9' ), ( 'vnm431', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '12W' ), ( 'xyzzy', '2012-01-01T12:00:00', '6N' );
select * from @Victims;

-- Do something.
declare @TargetDate as Date, @TargetEmployeeId as VarChar(10), @ShoeSize as VarChar(6);
select @TargetDate = '20120101', @TargetEmployeeId = 'vnm432';

select top 1 @ShoeSize = ShoeSize
  from @Employees
  where EmployeeId = @TargetEmployeeId and Cast( HireDate as Date ) = @TargetDate;
if @@RowCount = 1
  begin
  -- Process and return.
  select 'Employees' as [Table], @ShoeSize as ShowSize;
  return
  end

select top 1 @ShoeSize = ShoeSize
  from @Victims
  where EmployeeId = @TargetEmployeeId and Cast( HireDate as Date ) = @TargetDate;
if @@RowCount = 1
  begin
  -- Process and return.
  select 'Victims' as [Table], @ShoeSize as ShowSize;
  return
  end
```